How do I flip the character to the left in Unity?
I assumed in Unity that the character was moving to the left in the animation or stopped on the way. I set it to do so using the recording function of the animation function.
I made the animation a blend tree to rotate left and right in these situations, but it doesn't work well. I can't see the picture that's rotated to the left.
 private void LateUpdate()
    {
        // Update animator
        anim.SetFloat("DirX", movement.x);
        anim.SetFloat("DirY", movement.y);
        anim.SetBool("Idle", movement.magnitude == 0); 
    }

This is the code that I want to modify. I gave each of the animations of the blending tree to match the value of this code,
(Example: left -1, right +1, float value for DirX)
In the animation preview, even though the Sprite is flipped, it doesn't move as expected when it actually runs.
This is my entire code.
Below is the full code, so it's better not to analyze it.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class PlayerManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    Coroutine playerMoveRoutine;

    public float speed = 500f;
    public float runSpeed = 200f;

    public GameObject player;
    public GameObject rightArrow;
    public GameObject leftArrow;
    public GameObject[] backgrounds;
    public GameObject[] Borders;

    private Vector2 movement; //Use the direction key to move
    private bool isRunning;
    private Animator anim;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    private void Start()
    {
        anim = player.GetComponent<Animator>();
        rb = player.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    
    private void Update()
    {
        // Get input
        movement.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        movement.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        isRunning = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightShift);

        
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) // Left mouse click detection
        {
            Vector2 worldPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(worldPoint, Vector2.zero);

            if (hit.collider != null)
            {
                
                if (hit.collider.gameObject == rightArrow)
                {
                    int clickX = 1;
                    // If we're already moving, cancel that coroutine so the two don't execute at the same time
                    if (playerMoveRoutine != null)
                    {
                        StopCoroutine(playerMoveRoutine);
                    }
                    playerMoveRoutine = StartCoroutine(ArrowClick(clickX));

                }
                else if (hit.collider.gameObject == leftArrow)
                {
                    int clickX = -1;
                    // If we're already moving, cancel that coroutine so the two don't execute at the same time
                    if (playerMoveRoutine != null)
                    {
                        StopCoroutine(playerMoveRoutine);
                    }
                    playerMoveRoutine = StartCoroutine(ArrowClick(clickX));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator ArrowClick(int _clickX)
    {
        float speed = 200;
        Vector2 target = new Vector2(500 * _clickX, 0);
        while (Vector2.Distance(player.transform.position, target) > 0.05f)
        {
            // Changed from hardcoded "10" to rather be based on the "Time.deltaTime": enables framerate independence (player will move the same amount in a second, regardless of FPS)
            player.transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(player.transform.position, target, speed * Time.deltaTime);

            // Tells the game to wait a frame before continuing execution
            yield return null;
        }
    }


    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // Move the character
        float currentSpeed = isRunning ? speed * runSpeed : speed;
        Vector2 velocity = movement.normalized * currentSpeed;
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + velocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        // Update animator
        anim.SetFloat("DirX", movement.x);
        anim.SetFloat("DirY", movement.y);
        anim.SetBool("Idle", movement.magnitude == 0);
    }
}

Here is my photo






define "doesnt move as expected" did you debug the animations?

"doesn't move as expected" is
Assume: "When you move to or stop to the left", that is, "when the value of DirX is -1, or when the value of DirX is -1 and then changes to 0"
Result: Defined that the character "doesn't move while upside down".
(Not affected by the DirY value.)
So to sum up, all I want is for the player to look to the left as they move to the left.
